# How to fetch data from html tag that stored in Salesforce marketing cloud data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, content-builder

Example :

1. I have stored below html tag as one field in data extension. I need to retrieve the href url from this. How to retrieve this ? and also How to retrieve "Visit google.com!" from html stored in data extension
2. How to send the HTML code in the data extension field as an email attachment? How to send the below code as email attachment in email ?

HTML :

```html
<h1> The a element </h1>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Visit google.com!<a>
```

Comment: What approach have you tried? In what context do you want to retrieve this information? SQL, CloudPage or at send time in a message? Are you able to  retrieve the full row? Share some code you tried to use

Comment: I need to extract the url alone from html which stored in data extension.Then i use url as attachment in email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AMPscript `RegExMatch` function would help to get the URL.

**Update** to get both URL and link text.
Try this:

```
%%[
  set @html = AttributeValue('Your column name');

  set @url_Pattern = '(?<=href=").*(?=")'
  set @linkText_Pattern = '(?<=>).*(?=<a>)'

  set @url = RegExMatch(@html, @url_Pattern, 0)
  set @linkText = RegExMatch(@html, @linkText_Pattern, 0)
]%%

URL: %%=v(@url)=%%<br>
Link Text: %%=v(@linkText)=%%
```

Reference: [RegExMatch](https://ampscript.guide/regexmatch/) function

Comment: Thanks @DucLe Its working fine as i expected https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/83900/duc-le

Comment: How to retrieve "Visit W3Schools.com!" from html stored in data extension

Comment: @TestSFMC Update the answer

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/83900/duc-le  Do you know answer for my 2nd question. If yes means Please let me know